# Displaying Category in sidebar post widget but not in the loop on home

Tags: categories, loop, exclude

I've seen many pages on how to exclude a category from the home page entirely.

I am setting up a site to have a widget called News that displays the latest news items on the right but it seems like overkill to have them there and in the loop going down the page as well.

This code, however, hides it from everything on the home page as does many of the plugins I could find:

```
function only_portfolio_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '3' );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_portfolio_category' );
```

Other sites mention editing the Loop to exclude it only from the main listing but I am lost as to where in the Loop to add code to get this done and how.

Here is a diagram to illustrate:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: It would be easier to just set up a separate sidebar for the homepage only. That way you can exclude the news widget on the homepage but keep it on whatever other sidebars you want.

Comment: Not sure that answers the question though. I want the news items to appear only in widget on the home page, not in the loop of other blog posts. For ease of learning I'm using a child of 2017 theme.